# how to tell if my code is compiled in 32 or 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, cygwin, 32-bit

I am using Cygwin (64 bit) on a 64 bit Windows 8 laptop. I notice a lot of the libraries/binaries/etc. say "Cygwin32" on them. If I compile my code using these, will my software take full advantage of my 64 bit processor?

How can I tell if my programs are running in 32 bit vs 64 bit?

Comment: Cygwin32 simply indicates its the win32 library not a reference to anything else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find out what format an executable is with `file`.

```
# file putty.exe
putty.exe: PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit
```

Comment: that is for Linux. Is there something like that for Windows (Author mentioned Windows 8 laptop).

Comment: Cygwin is Linux-like environment for Windows. Generally an install would include utilities like file.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I did not know.

Comment: Thanks, the result I got was `PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows`. What does this mean as far as 32 vs 64 bit?

Comment: x86-64 means it is a 64 bit program.